# how to add onclick or mouseover event to imagebutton in runtime

Tags: asp.net, events, c#-4.0, imagebutton

ive imagebuttons which created in runtime from database and i need to add them onclick or mouseover event but i failed

```
imagebutton.click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imageButton_Click);
```

im adding this when i created imagebuttons, what i need else

also i tried javascript but its not firing too;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetProductImage(imgID) {
    document.getElementById('imgProduct').src=document.getElementById(imgID).src;
}
</script>

imgProductImage.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:SetProductImage('" + imgProductImage.ID + "')";
```

thank you...

Comment: It depends a bit where in your code you create the button and you wire up the event. Can you provide some more relevant code?

Comment: on pageload i create the button and event but i cant trigger the event

Comment: @thiefmaster it doesnt work after i removed javascript:

Comment: javascript or c# doesnt matter i need to make it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment I am assuming you are doing something like:

```
void Page_Load(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
    img.click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imageButton_Click);
    Controls.Add(img);
}
```

This won't work because the PostBack mechanism sends the Id of the control back in the EventTarget field and the target isn't specified so it doesn't know where to handle it.

To get this to work properly I usually wrap the display in a custom user control and override the `CreateChildControls()` method.  This ensures that the control is created at the correct time and is available when the postback handling is done.

Comment: but there is a problem... i can get in event but i cannot change imageurl of image why is that... and how can fix it....

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to fire up a code behind event? or a javascript event? If you are trying to add a javascript event to your element, you should **Add** the attribute. It's not currently there when you use: Attributes["onclick"]. So It'd be like:

```
imgProductImage.Attributes.Add("onclick","SetProductImage('" + imgProductImage.ID + "')");
```

Comment: i tried nothing happens, i mean  it doesnt reach the javascript block

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think I found out what you are trying to achieve. You have to explicitly set the ID of the control in Page_Load:

```
ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
img.ID = "image1";
img.ImageUrl = "YOUR_IMAGE_URL";
img.OnClientClick = "SetProductImage('" + img.ID + "');return false;";
Controls.Add(img);
```

Just make sure if you have to define multiple image buttones, Set a unique ID for each of them.